# PHP constant not defined when using cli but works via apache

Tags: php, apache, command-line-interface, constants

I have a scenario where a static function in an included file will see my `defined` values if I trigger that code via web-request but when the exact same code is triggered via a cron fired schedule the `defined` values are not seen as defined. I have reduced my code scenario to the simplest possible form as follows:

**Update** I put an `error_log(print_r(get_defined_constants(true),true));` in the file and compared the results between a web execution and a cron execution and the only thing different is my missing constant on the cron side and the pcntl extension constants on the cron web side

**note**: all web requests require this settings file and have no issue
**note**: I have other *scheduled* files that see the defined values
**note**: I have other web files that utilize this *class* and its functions without issue.

**confirmed**: The settings file is included
**confirmed**: The function is being called

I feel like I'm missing something completely obvious or highly esoteric.

```
//-- settings file
...
define("NEED_THIS_CONST","DOODLYDOO");
...
```

```
//-- class file
class vendor {
  public static function dothis() {
    error_log("reached the file");
    if(!defined("NEED_THIS_CONST")) {
      error_log("not defined");
    else
      error_log("defined");
    }
  }
}
```

```
//-- requested file
...
require_once("settings.php");
include_once("vendor.php");
vendor::dothis();
```

Comment: I can't duplicate it after fixing your mismatched braces.

Comment: A guess: parts of the code use short tags (`<? ... ?>`). CLI has them disabled, mod_php or CGI doesn't.

Comment: Never require file like this: `require_once("settings.php");` – should be `require_once(__DIR__ . "/settings.php");` – always. You should read what is the difference between a relative path and an absolute path and why it matters in Linux… especially between different environments.

Comment: Why @emix? The way our environment is set up changing to what you suggest would break things.

Comment: Alvaro: Thanks for the tip but doesn't apply "I have other scheduled files that see the defined values". I should clarify, other scheduled _cron_ files see all the other defined values in the settings file, this one file (only one to use NEED_THIS_CONST) just doesn't see NEED_THIS_CONST

Comment: emix: the entire system works fine, 300k lines of code, this is the one issue I have. It's not not failure to include and I use proper pathing I hand typed this example for simplicity.

Comment: New revelation! the somehow the cron executed file see's values from the settings file from before I modified it adding NEED_THIS_CONST but the web executions see the current state of the settings file.

Comment: Depending on the platform you are using the CLI version and web version of PHP may be using different INI files and/or have a different include path.

Comment: This is why files should be loaded using an absolute path. Like I said in the very beginning. Also check if opcache isn’t enabled for CLI.

Comment: If my include files fall outside of the web root how is `__DIR__` going to help may I ask? Yes, I know we've diverged from the question a bit :)

Comment: UPDATE: This files exists singularly in the file system AND when i run php schedule.php from shell the updated settings.php file is used, when I let cron trigger php schedule.php the log shows it's seeing the contents of settings.php from days ago and not current (I commented out specific define lines to test). I've killed all cron processes and even did a stop start on the service and yet whenever triggered from cron it see's settings that aren't in the file anymore.

Comment: Is cron running as the same user as the shell user you are testing with?

Comment: SORRY. I failed to confirm my facts. At some point I had copied the settings file (a hidden file) to my home directory to scp it, and for some reason this script (not in the same path) was using that settings file when triggered from cron, when I removed that copy (not a link btw) cron instantly started using the live file.

Comment: So everything is good now?

Comment: I still dont know why that copy was used as the actual include pathing is relative pathing to the absolute codebase root that wouldn't find that file anyway. I'm lost as to the how, shadow file handle? On Linux? Never heard of that. It works now though.

Comment: Everything is good. @Dave yes cron and shell are the same user. Removing the settings file copy (in a path not relative to the code) resolved cron's issue. I would LOVE to know why cron kept pulling that file.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved. At some point I had copied the settings file (a hidden file) to my home directory to scp it, and for some reason this script (not in the same path) was using that settings file when triggered from cron, when I removed that copy (not a link) cron instantly started using the live file. I still dont know why that copy was used as the actual include pathing is relative pathing to the absolute codebase root that wouldn't find that file anyway. I'm lost as to the how, shadow file handle? On Linux? Never heard of that. It works now though.